# Vercel Deployment Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, vercel

If I run vercel in my client directory, the error Command "npm install" exited with 1 will happen. And Error: Check your logs at https://client-xxx.vercel.app/_logs or run
This is the vercel log outputs

```
[02:10:17.910] Running build in San Francisco, USA (West) – sfo1
[02:10:17.968] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[02:10:18.228] Previous build caches not available
[02:10:18.412] Downloading 65 deployment files...
[02:10:19.899] Running "vercel build"
[02:10:20.485] Vercel CLI 28.18.5
[02:10:21.202] Installing dependencies...
[02:10:23.470] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[02:10:23.474] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[02:10:23.474] npm ERR! 
[02:10:23.475] npm ERR! While resolving: react-credit-cards@0.8.3
[02:10:23.475] npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
[02:10:23.475] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[02:10:23.475] npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
[02:10:23.476] npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.11.0 || ^17 || ^18" from @auth0/auth0-react@2.0.1
[02:10:23.476] npm ERR!   node_modules/@auth0/auth0-react
[02:10:23.476] npm ERR!     @auth0/auth0-react@"^2.0.1" from the root project
[02:10:23.476] npm ERR!   19 more (@react-aria/ssr, @react-google-maps/api, ...)
[02:10:23.476] npm ERR! 
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-credit-cards@0.8.3
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR! node_modules/react-credit-cards
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR!   react-credit-cards@"^0.8.3" from the root project
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR! 
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
[02:10:23.477] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[02:10:23.478] npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-credit-cards@0.8.3
[02:10:23.478] npm ERR!   node_modules/react-credit-cards
[02:10:23.478] npm ERR!     react-credit-cards@"^0.8.3" from the root project
[02:10:23.478] npm ERR! 
[02:10:23.478] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[02:10:23.481] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[02:10:23.481] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[02:10:23.481] npm ERR! 
[02:10:23.481] npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[02:10:23.482] 
[02:10:23.482] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[02:10:23.482] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-04-24T09_10_21_553Z-debug-0.log
[02:10:23.513] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
[02:10:23.753] Deployment completed
[02:10:23.716] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

And my package.json is like this

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.0.1",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.18.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "card-js": "^1.0.13",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-credit-cards": "^0.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5"
  }
}
```

Please help me to checkout. The API is served correctly in Google Cloud